# vim gd search for function name

Tags: vim

If I use gd on the function name for the following:

```
def function_name(parameter1, parameter2):
...
...
```

vim searches for "function_name(parameter1" but I want it to search only "function_name". 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Vim's `gd` is not actually a "search" function, but a **goto** (therefore the `g`), in this case to a local declaration. There are several ways to try searching for function_name, the easiest probably being `*`  which will search for a word under its cursor. `n` will move you through each of them in the "forward" direction, while `#` will do the same only "backwards".

Comment: Even * does the same thing i.e., search for "function_name(parameter1" but I want it to search only "function_name". It considers that white-space(" ") is the end of function name but I want to set "(" as the end of function name

Comment: @Parikshit - So you want it to end the search at (C    <-- at the C for cursor position?

Comment: @Idigas - Yes. I want it to end search at (

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is that [`iskeyword`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'iskeyword') includes the `(` character.

`*`/`#` will use `iskeyword` to determine the full *word* under the cursor. In my case if I have the following file:

```
function foobar_name(params) {
}

call function_name(param1);
        ^-- Cursor is here
```

If I press <kbd>*</kbd> then Vim will execute: `/\<function_name\><Cr>`.

My `iskeyword` looks like this: `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`

From [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'iskeyword'):

```
                                                *'iskeyword'* *'isk'*
'iskeyword' 'isk'       string (Vim default for MS-DOS and Win32:
                                            "@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"
                                  otherwise:  "@,48-57,_,192-255"
                                Vi default: "@,48-57,_")
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
        Keywords are used in searching and recognizing with many commands:
        "w", "*", "[i", etc.  It is also used for "\k" in a |pattern|.  See
        'isfname' for a description of the format of this option.  For C
        programs you could use "a-z,A-Z,48-57,_,.,-,>".
        For a help file it is set to all non-blank printable characters except
        '*', '"'' and '|' (so that CTRL-] on a command finds the help for that
        command).
        When the 'lisp' option is on the '-' character is always included.
        NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
        set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```